# How to show the enter button in keyboard after adding textNoSuggestions to editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, edittextpreference

Basically I'm trying to remove the suggestion underline from the editText and which is done by `textNoSuggestions` in `editText` . But now the problem is keyboard is not showing the enter button . So, I wonder how to show the enterKey even after adding the flag ?

Code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTxt"
        android:textColor="#001919"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:background="#fff"/>
```

Comment: Add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#001919"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```